# After updating pods facing extra argument error

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login, google-signin

My below code working very well before updating pod.

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

         let googleDidHandle = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation) 

         let facebookDidHandle = ApplicationDelegate.shared.application( application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)

         return googleDidHandle || facebookDidHandle
}
```

But today i have updated the pod and i got the below errors

> Extra argument 'sourceApplication' in call

in open URL method in AppDelegate method

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
```

I got below error at above line

> Value of type 'GIDSignIn?' has no member 'uiDelegate'

```
extension LoginViewController: GIDSignInDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

}
```

I got below error at above line

> Use of undeclared type 'GIDSignInUIDelegate'

## EDIT

After set GoogSignIn specif version to 4.4.0, the above errors gone but i'm facing an error while Re-Authenticate the Firebase user.

### Error

> Variable 'credential' used before being initialized

Here is my another question link: [Firebase User re-authentication initialising error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57704646/firebase-user-re-authentication-initialising-error)

how can i fix this?

Comment: Change it to `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self`

Comment: @VinuJacob, it already written by me.

Comment: you are calling `uiDelegate`. Call `delegate`

Comment: And open URL function change to `func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool { }`

Comment: @Kuldeep `GIDSignInUIDelegate`  is removed from updated `Pod`. To use it you have to install specific version of pod which is `pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 4.1.1'` then you can access `GIDSignInUIDelegate` Or I would suggest to update your code according to new update

Comment: @PiyushPatel, after specifying the GoogleSignIn specific version `'GoogleSignIn', '~> 4.4.0'` i am getting an error while Re-Authenticate the Firebase User. will you please look into this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57704646/firebase-user-re-authentication-initialising-error

Answer (score 1):

After Updating GoogleSignIn Pod 4.4.0 to 5.0.1 need to update the GoogleSignIn integration code.

**In 4.4.0 - In open URL method in AppDelegate**

Replace the below code,

> GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication:
>   sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)

With

> GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)

Replace the below code,

> GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

With

> GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self

GIDSignInUIDelegate protocol removed in current update.