# Firebase User re-authentication initialising error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

When any user wants to update his/her password from app, i want to update that password of same FCM user and for that i have tried below code which define in official doc.

here is the screenshot of that
[image]

Here is my code

```
func authenticateAndUpdateFCMUserPassword(strNewPassword: String) {
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    var credential: AuthCredential

    // Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
    user?.reauthenticate(with: credential) { error in
        if let error = error {
            // An error happened.
        } else {
            // User re-authenticated.
        }
    }

    Auth.auth().currentUser?.updatePassword(to: strNewPassword) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error occur while updating password")
        }
        else {
            print("Password Updated Successfully")
        }
    }
}
```

But in above code i'm facing below error at `user?.reauthenticate` line

> Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type
>   'AuthDataResultCallback?' (aka 'Optional<(Optional,
>   Optional) -> ()>')

so i re write that by below code

```
user?.reauthenticate(with: credential, completion: { (dataResult, errorr) in
    if errorr != nil {
        // An error happened.
    } else {
        // User re-authenticated.
    }
})
```

but in above code i'm facing below error

> Variable 'credential' used before being initialized

**credential** is defined only once and never used before this

will anyone please let me know what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When I set my credential variable as below, the error went away for me:

```
var credential: AuthCredential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: email, password: password)
```

This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52160137/9625899